# Modify xslt according to the output xml

Tags: c#, xml, xslt

I am trying to modify my XSLT to get the required output. Listing the required input XML, output XML and XSLT file.

Here is my input XML

```
<NewDataSet>
    <Header>
        <BankName>SAMA</BankName>
        <CashCenterName>SAMA Riyadh</CashCenterName>
    </Header>
    <DepositorList>
        <ReferenceNumber>1</ReferenceNumber>
        <DepositList_Id>0</DepositList_Id>
        <PreparedBy>FZE</PreparedBy>
        <TotalContainerCount>2</TotalContainerCount>
        <ExpectedDate>2018-04-19T09:13:10-05:00</ExpectedDate>
        <DeclaredAmount>150000</DeclaredAmount>
    </DepositorList>
    <Carrier>
        <CarrierName>tns1:Commercial CIT</CarrierName>
        <CarrierNumber>10001</CarrierNumber>
        <CarrierLocationName>tns1:Riyadh</CarrierLocationName>
        <CarrierLocationNumber>100011</CarrierLocationNumber>
        <CarrierLocationRouteName>tns1:R1</CarrierLocationRouteName>
        <CarrierLocationRouteNumber>R1</CarrierLocationRouteNumber>
        <DepositList_Id>0</DepositList_Id>
    </Carrier>
    <Customer>
        <AccountNumber>ISB</AccountNumber>
        <LocationNumber>10065100</LocationNumber>
        <DepositList_Id>0</DepositList_Id>
    </Customer>
    <ContainerList>
        <ContainerNumber>903000033102</ContainerNumber>
        <ContainerList_Id>0</ContainerList_Id>
        <DeclaredAmount>50000</DeclaredAmount>
        <DepositList_Id>0</DepositList_Id>
    </ContainerList>
    <ContainerList>
        <ContainerNumber>903000033103</ContainerNumber>
        <ContainerList_Id>1</ContainerList_Id>
        <DeclaredAmount>100000</DeclaredAmount>
        <DepositList_Id>0</DepositList_Id>
    </ContainerList>
    <ContainerContentList>
        <ContainerContentList_Id>0</ContainerContentList_Id>
        <TotalRecordCount>1</TotalRecordCount>
        <ContainerList_Id>0</ContainerList_Id>
    </ContainerContentList>
    <ContainerContentList>
        <ContainerContentList_Id>1</ContainerContentList_Id>
        <TotalRecordCount>1</TotalRecordCount>
        <ContainerList_Id>1</ContainerList_Id>
    </ContainerContentList>
    <ContentCategory>
        <ISOCurrencyCode>SAR</ISOCurrencyCode>
        <InventoryType>Fit Currency</InventoryType>
        <InventorySubType>Fit</InventorySubType>
        <ContainerContentList_Id>0</ContainerContentList_Id>
    </ContentCategory>
    <ContentCategory>
        <ISOCurrencyCode>SAR</ISOCurrencyCode>
        <InventoryType>Fit Currency</InventoryType>
        <InventorySubType>Fit</InventorySubType>
        <ContainerContentList_Id>1</ContainerContentList_Id>
    </ContentCategory>
    <ContentCategoryItemList>
        <ItemFaceValue>5</ItemFaceValue>
        <ItemCount>10000</ItemCount>
        <DeclaredAmount>50000</DeclaredAmount>
        <ContentCategoryItemList_Id>0</ContentCategoryItemList_Id>
        <ContainerContentList_Id>0</ContainerContentList_Id>
    </ContentCategoryItemList>
    <ContentCategoryItemList>
        <ItemFaceValue>10</ItemFaceValue>
        <ItemCount>10000</ItemCount>
        <DeclaredAmount>100000</DeclaredAmount>
        <ContentCategoryItemList_Id>1</ContentCategoryItemList_Id>
        <ContainerContentList_Id>1</ContainerContentList_Id>
    </ContentCategoryItemList>
    <CategoryItemUnitList>
        <InventoryUnitName>Bundle</InventoryUnitName>
        <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
        <UnitAmount>5000</UnitAmount>
        <UnitWeight />
        <MeasurementUnit />
        <BeginSerialNumber />
        <Series />
        <EndSerialNumber />
        <ContentCategoryItemList_Id>0</ContentCategoryItemList_Id>
    </CategoryItemUnitList>
    <CategoryItemUnitList>
        <InventoryUnitName>Bundle</InventoryUnitName>
        <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
        <UnitAmount>10000</UnitAmount>
        <UnitWeight />
        <MeasurementUnit />
        <BeginSerialNumber />
        <Series />
        <EndSerialNumber />
        <ContentCategoryItemList_Id>1</ContentCategoryItemList_Id>
    </CategoryItemUnitList>
</NewDataSet>
```

The output I am looking for is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tns:DepositNotificationFile xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.gide.com/vmsng/integration/dn/schema/message DepositNotification.messages.xsd " xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tns1="http://www.gide.com/vmsng/integration/dn/schema/type" xmlns:tns="http://www.gide.com/vmsng/integration/dn/schema/message">
 <tns:Header>
     <tns1:BankName>SAMA</tns1:BankName>
     <tns1:CashCenterName>SAMA Riyadh</tns1:CashCenterName>
 </tns:Header>
 <tns:DepositList>
      <tns1:ReferenceNumber>00000001</tns1:ReferenceNumber>
 <tns1:Carrier>
      <tns1:CarrierName>tns1:Commercial CIT</tns1:CarrierName>
      <tns1:CarrierNumber>10001</tns1:CarrierNumber>
      <tns1:CarrierLocationName>tns1:Riyadh</tns1:CarrierLocationName>
      <tns1:CarrierLocationNumber>100011</tns1:CarrierLocationNumber>
      <tns1:CarrierLocationRouteName>tns1:R1</tns1:CarrierLocationRouteName>
      <tns1:CarrierLocationRouteNumber>R1</tns1:CarrierLocationRouteNumber>
 </tns1:Carrier>
 <tns1:Customer>
      <tns1:AccountNumber>ISB</tns1:AccountNumber>
      <tns1:LocationNumber>10065100</tns1:LocationNumber>
 </tns1:Customer>
 <tns1:ContainerList>
      <tns1:ContainerNumber>903000033102</tns1:ContainerNumber>
      <tns1:ContainerContentList>
           <tns1:ContentCategory>
                <tns1:ISOCurrencyCode>SAR</tns1:ISOCurrencyCode>
                <tns1:InventoryType>Fit Currency</tns1:InventoryType>
                <tns1:InventorySubType>Fit</tns1:InventorySubType>
           </tns1:ContentCategory>
           <tns1:ContentCategoryItemList>
                <tns1:ItemFaceValue>5.0000</tns1:ItemFaceValue>
                <tns1:ItemCount>10000</tns1:ItemCount>
                <tns1:DeclaredAmount>50000.00</tns1:DeclaredAmount>
                <tns1:CategoryItemUnitList>
                     <tns1:InventoryUnitName>Bundle</tns1:InventoryUnitName>
                     <tns1:UnitQuantity>10</tns1:UnitQuantity>
                     <tns1:UnitAmount>5000.0</tns1:UnitAmount>
                     <tns1:UnitWeight/>
                     <tns1:MeasurementUnit/>
                     <tns1:BeginSerialNumber/>
                     <tns1:Series/>
                     <tns1:EndSerialNumber/>
               </tns1:CategoryItemUnitList>
          </tns1:ContentCategoryItemList>
          <tns1:TotalRecordCount>1</tns1:TotalRecordCount>
     </tns1:ContainerContentList>
     <tns1:DeclaredAmount>50000.00</tns1:DeclaredAmount>
  </tns1:ContainerList>
  <tns1:ContainerList>
       <tns1:ContainerNumber>903000033103</tns1:ContainerNumber>
       <tns1:ContainerContentList>
            <tns1:ContentCategory>
                 <tns1:ISOCurrencyCode>SAR</tns1:ISOCurrencyCode>
                 <tns1:InventoryType>Fit Currency</tns1:InventoryType>
                 <tns1:InventorySubType>Fit</tns1:InventorySubType>
            </tns1:ContentCategory>
            <tns1:ContentCategoryItemList>
                 <tns1:ItemFaceValue>10.0000</tns1:ItemFaceValue>
                 <tns1:ItemCount>10000</tns1:ItemCount>
                 <tns1:DeclaredAmount>100000.00</tns1:DeclaredAmount>
                 <tns1:CategoryItemUnitList>
                              <tns1:InventoryUnitName>Bundle</tns1:InventoryUnitName>
                      <tns1:UnitQuantity>10</tns1:UnitQuantity>
                      <tns1:UnitAmount>10000.0</tns1:UnitAmount>
                      <tns1:UnitWeight/>
                      <tns1:MeasurementUnit/>
                      <tns1:BeginSerialNumber/>
                      <tns1:Series/>
                      <tns1:EndSerialNumber/>
                 </tns1:CategoryItemUnitList>
           </tns1:ContentCategoryItemList>
           <tns1:TotalRecordCount>1</tns1:TotalRecordCount>
     </tns1:ContainerContentList>
     <tns1:DeclaredAmount>100000.00</tns1:DeclaredAmount>
  </tns1:ContainerList>
  <tns1:PreparedBy>FZE</tns1:PreparedBy>
  <tns1:TotalContainerCount>2</tns1:TotalContainerCount>
  <tns1:ExpectedDate>2018-04-19T09:13:10-05:00</tns1:ExpectedDate>
  <tns1:DeclaredAmount>150000.00</tns1:DeclaredAmount>
 </tns:DepositList>
</tns:DepositNotificationFile>
```

Please suggest the right XSLT to get the correct results:

My current XSLT so far

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/NewDataSet">
        <NewDataSet>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Header"/>
            <xsl:for-each select="DepositorList">
                <DepositorList>
                    <xsl:variable name="DepositList_Id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="DepositList_Id"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="ContainerList_Id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../ContainerList[DepositList_Id=$DepositList_Id]/ContainerList_Id"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="ContainerContentList_Id">
                        <xsl:value-of select="../ContainerContentList[ContainerList_Id=$DepositList_Id]/ContainerList_Id/ContainerContentList_Id"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../ContainerList[DepositList_Id=$DepositList_Id]"/>                                           
                    <xsl:copy-of select="../ContainerContentList[ContainerList_Id=$ContainerList_Id]"/>             
                </DepositorList>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </NewDataSet>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I have deleted the solution since the updated XML is completely different from the original one for which the solution was provided.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I don't always downvote questions featuring urgent begging, but I have done on this occasion. Here, the question attracted a good answer, and then the question was overwritten with a fresh question, causing the helper to have wasted their time. You have been most lucky that they were willing to rewrite their answer - that is quite unusual. For the future, I would suggest that once you receive an answer on a question, keep your question edits to cosmetic changes, and do not try to work around question rate-limiter or question bans.

Comment: I would make sure this doesn't happen again, It was an urgent issues and I am new on stackoverflow.. going forward I will keep it in mind..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution uses nested `<xsl:for-each>` loops filtering the data by matching the different `*_Id` element values. It may not be the most optimal solution to get the desired output due to the use of nested `for-each` loops.

Please note the elements in the output that has been shared belong to different namespaces which has not been considered in the XSLT since the namespaces are not present in the input. If the namespaces are required in output and not present in input then the XSLT will have to be modified to handle each element separately.

Additionally some of the elements in the output, especially numbers, have been formatted in the output either for amounts (`#.00` or `#.0`) or a different number format, which has resulted in using `copy-of` element wise in such scenarios.

XSLT Solution

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />

    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
        <DepositNotificationFile>
            <xsl:copy-of select="Header" />
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </DepositNotificationFile>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="DepositorList">
        <DepositList>
            <xsl:variable name="depLstId" select="DepositList_Id" />
            <!-- format reference number -->
            <ReferenceNumber><xsl:value-of select="format-number(ReferenceNumber, '000000000')" /></ReferenceNumber>
            <!-- create <Carrier> element and copy all children except <DepositList_Id>  -->
            <Carrier>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../Carrier[DepositList_Id = $depLstId]/*[not(self::DepositList_Id)]" />
            </Carrier>
            <!-- create <Customer> element and copy all children except <DepositList_Id>  -->
            <Customer>
                <xsl:copy-of select="../Customer[DepositList_Id = $depLstId]/*[not(self::DepositList_Id)]" />
            </Customer>
            <!-- loop for <ContainerList> matching <DepositList_Id> -->
            <xsl:for-each select="../ContainerList[DepositList_Id = $depLstId]">
                <ContainerList>
                    <xsl:variable name="contLstId" select="ContainerList_Id" />
                    <xsl:copy-of select="ContainerNumber" />

                    <!-- create <ContainerContentList> -->
                    <ContainerContentList>
                        <!-- loop for <ContainerContentList> matching <ContainerList_Id> -->
                        <xsl:for-each select="../ContainerContentList[ContainerList_Id = $contLstId]">
                            <xsl:variable name="contentLstId" select="ContainerContentList_Id" />
                            <!-- create <ContentCategory> and copy all children except <ContainerContentList_Id> -->
                            <ContentCategory>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="../ContentCategory[ContainerContentList_Id = $contentLstId]/*[not(self::ContainerContentList_Id)]" />
                            </ContentCategory>

                            <!-- create <ContentCategoryItemList> and copy, format children -->
                            <ContentCategoryItemList>
                                <ItemFaceValue><xsl:value-of select="format-number(../ContentCategoryItemList[ContainerContentList_Id = $contentLstId]/ItemFaceValue, '#.0000')" /></ItemFaceValue>
                                <xsl:copy-of select="../ContentCategoryItemList[ContainerContentList_Id = $contentLstId]/ItemCount" />
                                <DeclaredAmount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(../ContentCategoryItemList[ContainerContentList_Id = $contentLstId]/DeclaredAmount, '#.00')" /></DeclaredAmount>
                                <xsl:variable name="ctgyItemLstId" select="../ContentCategoryItemList[ContainerContentList_Id = $contentLstId]/ContentCategoryItemList_Id" />

                                <!-- create <CategoryItemUnitList> -->
                                <CategoryItemUnitList>
                                    <!-- loop for <CategoryItemUnitList> matching <ContentCategoryItemList_Id> -->
                                    <xsl:for-each select="../CategoryItemUnitList[ContentCategoryItemList_Id = $ctgyItemLstId]">
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="InventoryUnitName | UnitQuantity" />
                                        <UnitAmount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(UnitAmount, '#.0')" /></UnitAmount>
                                        <xsl:copy-of select="UnitWeight | MeasurementUnit | BeginSerialNumber | Series | EndSerialNumber" />
                                    </xsl:for-each>
                                </CategoryItemUnitList>
                            </ContentCategoryItemList>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </ContainerContentList>
                    <DeclaredAmount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DeclaredAmount,'#.00')" /></DeclaredAmount>
                </ContainerList>                
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:copy-of select="PreparedBy | TotalContainerCount | ExpectedDate" />
            <DeclaredAmount><xsl:value-of select="format-number(DeclaredAmount, '#.00')" /></DeclaredAmount>
        </DepositList>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output

```
<DepositNotificationFile>
    <Header>
        <BankName>SAMA</BankName>
        <CashCenterName>SAMA Riyadh</CashCenterName>
    </Header>
    <DepositList>
        <ReferenceNumber>000000001</ReferenceNumber>
        <Carrier>
            <CarrierName>tns1:Commercial CIT</CarrierName>
            <CarrierNumber>10001</CarrierNumber>
            <CarrierLocationName>tns1:Riyadh</CarrierLocationName>
            <CarrierLocationNumber>100011</CarrierLocationNumber>
            <CarrierLocationRouteName>tns1:R1</CarrierLocationRouteName>
            <CarrierLocationRouteNumber>R1</CarrierLocationRouteNumber>
        </Carrier>
        <Customer>
            <AccountNumber>ISB</AccountNumber>
            <LocationNumber>10065100</LocationNumber>
        </Customer>
        <ContainerList>
            <ContainerNumber>903000033102</ContainerNumber>
            <ContainerContentList>
                <ContentCategory>
                    <ISOCurrencyCode>SAR</ISOCurrencyCode>
                    <InventoryType>Fit Currency</InventoryType>
                    <InventorySubType>Fit</InventorySubType>
                </ContentCategory>
                <ContentCategoryItemList>
                    <ItemFaceValue>5.0000</ItemFaceValue>
                    <ItemCount>10000</ItemCount>
                    <DeclaredAmount>50000.00</DeclaredAmount>
                    <CategoryItemUnitList>
                        <InventoryUnitName>Bundle</InventoryUnitName>
                        <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
                        <UnitAmount>5000.0</UnitAmount>
                        <UnitWeight />
                        <MeasurementUnit />
                        <BeginSerialNumber />
                        <Series />
                        <EndSerialNumber />
                    </CategoryItemUnitList>
                </ContentCategoryItemList>
            </ContainerContentList>
            <DeclaredAmount>50000.00</DeclaredAmount>
        </ContainerList>
        <ContainerList>
            <ContainerNumber>903000033103</ContainerNumber>
            <ContainerContentList>
                <ContentCategory>
                    <ISOCurrencyCode>SAR</ISOCurrencyCode>
                    <InventoryType>Fit Currency</InventoryType>
                    <InventorySubType>Fit</InventorySubType>
                </ContentCategory>
                <ContentCategoryItemList>
                    <ItemFaceValue>10.0000</ItemFaceValue>
                    <ItemCount>10000</ItemCount>
                    <DeclaredAmount>100000.00</DeclaredAmount>
                    <CategoryItemUnitList>
                        <InventoryUnitName>Bundle</InventoryUnitName>
                        <UnitQuantity>10</UnitQuantity>
                        <UnitAmount>10000.0</UnitAmount>
                        <UnitWeight />
                        <MeasurementUnit />
                        <BeginSerialNumber />
                        <Series />
                        <EndSerialNumber />
                    </CategoryItemUnitList>
                </ContentCategoryItemList>
            </ContainerContentList>
            <DeclaredAmount>100000.00</DeclaredAmount>
        </ContainerList>
        <PreparedBy>FZE</PreparedBy>
        <TotalContainerCount>2</TotalContainerCount>
        <ExpectedDate>2018-04-19T09:13:10-05:00</ExpectedDate>
        <DeclaredAmount>150000.00</DeclaredAmount>
    </DepositList>
</DepositNotificationFile>
```

Comment: please suggest new xslt for changed xml.. and deposit_Id is not constant it can be any number of deposit Id's

Comment: The solution has been updated based on the changed input XML. It might not be the most optimal solution due to the use of nested `for-each` loops.

Comment: @AniketV: if you write an answer and the question is substantially modified afterwards, you can either ask the question author to roll it back, roll it back yourself, or flag it for a moderator. It's not wrong to update your answer, if you are willing to do so, but note that unless community members object to this behaviour, a question author may repeatedly edit their question, expecting new help every time. Upvoted for the effort.

Comment: @halfer - Thanks for the suggestion. Will keep that in mind going forward.